# How can I test to see if a program is available in Make?

Tags: makefile

Here's what I have so far.  I'm not looking for RVM-specific answers – I need to be able to replace `rvm` with, say, `evm`.  Just wanted to pick something everyone would be familiar with :)

```
install_rvm:
ifeq ("`which rvm > /dev/null; echo $?`", "0")
    @echo "rvm already installed!"
else
    @echo "installing rvm..."
    install_rvm_cmd
endif
```

#### Edit

Sorry for not saying this up-front, but I would like `install_rvm_cmd` to be run as it would normally – I don't want to hide the install process from the user.

Comment: Define "not hide"? You want the executed command to be displayed to the user or you want the normal output from the command to be displayed to the user?

Comment: I want the executed command to be displayed to the user and, less challengingly, its normal output.  Effectively, I want *default* Make behavior (obeying in spirit all flags given by the user) with the added conditional.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
.PHONY: install_rvm
install_rvm:
    @if which rvm > /dev/null; then \
      echo "rvm already installed!"; \
    else \
      echo "installing rvm..."; \
      install_rvm_cmd; \
    fi
```

It would be possible to use `ifeq` but it would entail performing the `which rvm` check even if `install_rvm` is not an actual target in a specific run of `make`. (I'm assuming the general case in which `install_rvm` is just one target among many.)

Although the string `install_rmv_cmd` itself wont' be output by `make`, its *output* will be output as usual. If you really want to have `install_rmv_cmd` out on stdout, you can always add `echo install_rmv_cmd` just before the command itself. To avoid repetition you could have the `else` branch be:

```
  echo "installing rvm..."; \
  cmd=install_rmv_cmd; \
  echo $$cmd; \
  $$cmd; \
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Louis's answer, you can use `ifdef`.  For example:

```
EVM_LOCATION := $(shell which evm)
CASK_LOCATION := $(shell which cask)

install_cask:
ifdef CASK_LOCATION
    $(info cask is already installed!)
else
    curl -fsSkL https://raw.github.com/cask/cask/master/go | python
endif

install_evm:
ifdef EVM_LOCATION
    $(info evm is already installed!)
else
    curl -fsSkL https://raw.github.com/rejeep/evm/master/go | bash
endif
```

Comment: This is the "It would be possible to use ifeq but it would entail performing the which rvm check even if install_rvm is not an actual target in a specific run of make" idea that @Louis mentioned in his answer which has the drawback of running those `which` commands every time make is run regardless of target.

Comment: @EtanReisner Whoops, you're right. Credit where credit is due. The extra `which` commands aren't a great concern, but I can see your point in the general case.

Comment: How great of a concern the extra shell/`which` spawns are depends entirely on how many of these tests there are and how often `make` is run but yes it may not matter.

Comment: @EtanReisner My specific use case is https://github.com/vermiculus/sx.el/pull/203 (in progress). It's not a very large makefile for me, so the `which` option is most straightforward.  That said, I'm going to leave this Q open until tomorrow night to see if it attracts a cleaner answer.

Comment: @Louis Truly sorry about that :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this (untested) which uses a stamp file to avoid doing any work once it has been done.

```
install_rvm_stamp:
        __rvm=$$(command -v rvm);\
        if [ -z "$$__rvm" ] || ! "$$__rvm" --version >/dev/null 2>&1; then \
            echo "installing rvm..."; \
            install_rvm_cmd; \
        else \
            echo 'rvm already installed!'
        fi
        touch '$@'

.PHONY: install_rvm
install_rvm: install_rvm_stamp
```

Alternatively, if you don't mind not "function testing" the binary you could do something like this instead.

```
rvm_bin := $(or $(realpath /usr/local/bin/rvm),$(realpath /bin/rvm),$(realpath /usr/bin/rvm),do_install_rvm)
install_rvm: $(rvm_bin)

do_install_rvm:
        @echo "installing rvm..."
        install_rvm_cmd
```

One final comment, as an augmentation to the make-level `ifdef` option presented in your answer; if the targets in question are only intended to be run manually (and are not used as prerequisites for any other targets) then the extraneous `which` calls can be avoided with some extra make-level checking.

```
ifneq (,$(findstring install_evm,$(MAKECMDGOALS)))
    EVM_LOCATION := $(shell which evm)
endif
```

Wrap that in the following and you can avoid undefined variable warnings about `MAKECMDGOALS` if `--warn-undefined-variables` is used.

```
ifneq (undefined,$(origin MAKECMDGOALS))
....
endif
```

Comment: Hah! Nice approach :) It does dirty the worktree, though – but this is how Make was designed to behave (with the exception of all the crazy shell action).

Comment: You can use a separate (dot hidden) directory for these files if you really wanted to but yeah, that's a relatively small cost for this I think. Alternatively, you could actually use the path (or possible paths) to the binaries in question as the prerequisites of `install_rvm` and move the `install_rvm_cmd` to the recipe of that target directly.

Comment: Would it be poor practice to use the VCS repository as a container for these flags?  That's already something that can't (or shouldn't) be tracked.

Comment: If you mean a `.git` or `.svn` or whatever directory? It'd raise eyebrows if I saw it being done but it isn't an entirely horrible idea (though it does raise possible filename conflict issues).

Comment: I'm a little leery of recording system state with a stamp file. While it is rare that things get uninstalled without an explicit request for uninstallation on my part, sometimes, on some systems I've had uninstalls happening as side effects.

Comment: @Louis Indeed. Testing the actual functionality before you need it is always a good idea but this lets you have a quick test which can also do the install for you in the normal case if you want.